# 404 not found for Spring MVC on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am new to Spring MVC. I am trying to create a simple web application using Spring MVC and a Tomcat as a server. But when I deploy my project I get Error 404 not found.
Could you please help me?
Here is my web.xml

```
  <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-web-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/main/index</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
  </web-app>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/main")
  public class RootController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public String printHello(){
        return "index";
      }
    }
```

And here is my spring-web-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Comment: can you access the tomcat server page after you start the server? normally `http://localhost:8080/` if can just go to manager App and see your application is listed there.

Comment: @ Rajith Pemabandu, no I can't see my app there and I get nothing on http://localhost:8080/

Comment: If you just want to get a Spring MVC web app up and running quickly have you considered Spring Boot? You can get a project set up quickly from start.spring.io. If not can you please post the tomcat logs.

Comment: Can you post your jsp file as well? BTW, you don't need to list /main/index in welcome-file-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in structure of my project. I created it incorrectly and as a result there was a problem with correctness of whole structure of my project and visibilities of files in it. Creating new project helped me.

Answer (score 1):

By default server looks for the welcome file in following order:

```
<welcome-file-list> in web.xml
index.html
index.htm
index.jsp
```

If none of these files are found, server renders 404 error.